# Adding multiple validators to FormGroup in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

How can I add multiple validators to a FormGroup.

A FormControl can accept an array of validators, however a FormGroup cannot. Is there a workaround aside from creating a single custom validator?

I am using rc4.

Comment: Maybe via Validators.compose?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do but I get a weird error during compilation.
 Ex. `let myGroup = this.formBuilder.group({}, {validator: Validators.compose([this.myCustomValidator(variable1, variable2)])});`

Just to give you an idea of what myCustomValidator does, it returns a validator function `return (group: FormGroup): {[s: string]: boolean} => {}`

The error I get is:
`Argument of type '((group: FormGroup) => { [s: string]: boolean; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn[]'.`

Comment: Btw the custom validator by itself works fine like this: `let myGroup = this.formBuilder.group({}, {validator: this.myCustomValidator(variable1, variable2)});`

Comment: @DavidBulte I was able to get it to work with Validators.compose after all. I was importing Validators from '@angular/core' instead of '@angular/forms'. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Multiple validators can be combined through `Validators.compose()`.

From the [api reference](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#compose):

> compose(validators: ValidatorFn[]) : ValidatorFn
>
> Compose multiple validators into a single function that returns the union of the individual error maps.

Comment: documentation link is broken, but the answer still works

Comment: doesn't work for me. 
`{
          validator: Validators.compose(
            [
              this.validationFn1.bind(this),
              this.validationFn2.bind(this)
            ]
          )
        }`

Answer (score 8):

Actually, FormGroup did accept array of validators. Just that the interface not updated. Cast it to **any** will do. E.g.

```
<any>[Validators.required, Validators.minlength(2)]
```

Comment: Just tried it, although it doesn't throw an error only one of the validators works for some reason. Do you use FormBuilder.group or just plain FormGroup?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? @Maxim

Comment: @PriteshAcharya I just ended up using Validators.compose(). Also keep in mind that this question was asked in regards to Angular RC4, it is now on Angular 4 or something, I've since moved on to Vue.

Comment: I just used two validators (required, maxlength) and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using a FormGroup and a FormBuilder.
this is how i set two validators for email input:

```
emailForm : FormGroup;
CreatEmailForm(){
this.emailForm = this.formBuilder.group({
emial:["example@email.com", { validators: [Validator.required , Validators.email ]}],
context:[null , Validator.required]})
}
```

Comment: Read the question carefully!